# Where to save markdown file so that it displays over local host

Tags: python, flask, markdown

I am teaching myself Python and am still pretty new to it. I am building an API using Flask, and I'm trying to display the contents of a README.md file that I have written on the local host connection using a very simple Flask program. Here is my code:

```
import markdown
from flask import Flask
import markdown.extensions.fenced_code

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    readme_file = open('C:/Users/robin/PycharmProjects/vcpapiflask/venv/working_directory/aux_programs/README.md', 'r')
    md_template_string = markdown.markdown(readme_file.read(), extensions=["fenced_code"]
                                           )
    return md_template_string
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=TRUE)
```

When I run this and check my local host URL, I get an internal service error (500), and my Pycharm terminal says that the README file cannot be located (No such file or directory). Where should I save my file so that it can be located by my program?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not able to find your file given the absolute path you're passing it. However, it would be better to work with relative paths to allow your code to be portable. Place `README.md` in the same directory as your app.py.

```
import markdown
from flask import Flask
import markdown.extensions.fenced_code
#import pathlib
import pathlib

app = Flask(__name__)

# Then grab the app's path
app_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # You can then reference the file's path relative to the app's path. 
    readme_file = open(str(app_path)+'/README.md', 'r')
    ...
```

I've tested this and it works regardless of the working dir as I think this is the problem you're facing.

> I get an internal service error (500), and my Pycharm terminal says that the README file cannot be located (No such file or directory).

Make sure `app.run(debug=True)` while you're working on this. You'll get a stack trace rather than "internal service error". For instance, with the above code and the file removed I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/codesidian/Documents/README.md'
```

With that you can quickly check if that file actually exists, which it doesn't or shouldn't if you're seeing that.

Comment: Wow, thank you for that detailed response. I tried your addition to the code with a relative path for my markdown file, and am now getting the same error, except it shows the entire and CORRECT filepath for the markdown file in the error message (I've checked multiple times to make sure that it is the actual filepath). I'm not sure why this is happening, but thank you for your input.

Comment: I feel so dumb...even though I created my file in PyCharm as a markdown file, it saved to my computer as an undefined file. As soon as I specified it was a markdown file, everything worked perfectly. Thank you so much!